# Socket server on GAE?

Tags: actionscript-3, google-app-engine, xmpp

I've written a socket server using Node.JS which works pretty well, but I'd rather use GAE for live production so that I get the warm fuzzy Google feeling.

On the client side, I'm using Flash->AIR (Desktop, iOS, and Android).

Question is, it seems that GAE does not support inbound sockets exactly. For Go, There's the Channel API and the XMPP API.

Channel API: Only works with Javascript clients, not Actionscript.

XMPP API: It seems that the most up to date Actionscript API out there is from XIFF... documentation is sparse, website is convoluted, and all-in-all it does not inspire trust at the level I'm looking for. On top of this, I simply want a socket server to pass basic messages back and forth, with an understanding of "users" and "channels". XMPP seems to be quite a lot more than that, and therefore more moving parts that can go wrong.

What is the standard answer to someone who's looking to build a custom socket server using a service like GAE, and not using Javascript clients? Just use XMPP and pray, or some other angle here I'm not seeing?

Comment: In case it's not clear - "warm fuzzy google feeling" is more than that, it's having inherent load balancing, fault tolerance, and things like that which can be cost prohibitive to solve for many users on a small budget.

Comment: I think the service you are looking for is called Amazon :P but of course with less fuzzy warm feeling. Inbound sockets would be nice in GAE but seems like it's not going to happen.

Comment: Your choices are as you said - XMPP or channels with all the limitations etc, or use a Compute Engine or AWS.  

But if pubsubhub meets your requirements https://pubsubhubbub.googlecode.com/git/pubsubhubbub-core-0.4.html  then that might be an alternative    https://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/DeveloperGettingStartedGuide  - I couldn't find any flex/air stuff from a cursory glance, though flex/air seems to be a big dead end.